# Characterization of a set of 2D vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a set of $n$ 2D vectors $(x_1,y_1), ... ,(x_n,y_n)$ where all numbers are integers. Each vector is not parallel to (1,1) nor orthogonal to it.

> What is known about characterizations (algebraic ) of such set of vectors?

I am also interested in its applications.

Comment: They're not parallel to $(1,1)$, so $x_i\neq y_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$. They're not orthogonal to $(1,1)$, so $x_i+y_i\neq 0$ for each $i$.

Comment: @Dave Nice, Are you aware of any applications especially in coding theory?

Comment: @Dave Equivalently, $x_i-y_i \ne 0$ and $x_i+y_i \ne 0$.